# How to query SQL dynamic lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have to pull data from these tables

```
**PRODUCT**                 **LOOKUP_CATEGORY**
ID      ProductName         ID      Category
1       Memory1             1       Product Type
2       Memory2             2       DIMM Type
3       Headset1            3       Color
4       Headset2            4       Speed
5       Keyboard1           5       Form Factor
6       Keyboard2

**LOOKUP**
ID      CategoryID       Value
1       1                DRAM
2       1                Keyboard
3       1                Headset
4       2                Buffered
5       2                Unbuffered
6       3                Red
7       3                White
8       3                Yellow
9       4                2000Mhz
10      4                2300Mhz
11      4                2600Mhz
12      5                DIMM
13      5                SODIMM
14      5                Earbud
15      5                On-Ear

**PRODUCT_FEATURES**
ID     ProductID     LookupID
1      1             1
2      1             4
3      1             10
4      1             12
5      2             1
6      2             5
7      2             9
8      2             13
9      3             3
10     3             7
11     3             15
12     4             3
13     4             6
14     4             14
15     5             2
16     5             7
17     6             2
18     6             8
```

I would like to get the result set like this

```
ProductName     Type        DIMMType       Color      Speed      FormFactor
Memory1         DRAM        Buffered       NULL       2300Mhz    DIMM
Memory2         DRAM        Unbuffered     NULL       2000Mhz    SODIMM
Headset1        Headset     NULL           White      NULL       On-Ear
Headset2        Headset     NULL           Red        NULL       Earbud
Keyboard1       Keyboard    NULL           White      NULL       NULL
Keyboard2       Keyboard    NULL           Yellow     NULL       NULL
```

Basically, I would like to be able to get all the products.
How do I this without making function calls? My database is Microsoft SQL 2016

I have tried this, but it does not seem to work as expected because of those NULL values

```
Select p.ProductID, p.ProductNumber
 , lType.Value AS ProductType, lDimm.Value AS DimmType, lSpeed.Value AS Speed, lColor.Value AS Color, lFactor.Value AS FormFactor
From PRODUCT p
Left Join PRODUCT_FEATURES xType On p.ProductID = xType.ProductID
Inner Join LOOKUP lType On xType.LookupID = lType.LookupID
Inner Join LOOKUP_CATEGORY lcType On lType.CategoryID = lcType.LookupCategoryID And lcType.Category = 'Product Type'
Left Join PRODUCT_FEATURES xDimm On p.ProductID = xDimm.ProductID
Inner Join LOOKUP lDimm On xDimm.LookupID = lDimm.LookupID
Inner Join LOOKUP_CATEGORY lcDimm On lDimm.CategoryID = lcDimm.LookupCategoryID And lcDimm.Category = 'DIMM Type'
Left Join PRODUCT_FEATURES xSpeed On p.ProductID = xSpeed.ProductID
Inner Join LOOKUP lSpeed On xSpeed.LookupID = lSpeed.LookupID
Inner Join LOOKUP_CATEGORY lcSpeed On lSpeed.CategoryID = lcSpeed.LookupCategoryID And lcSpeed.Category = 'Speed'
Left Join PRODUCT_FEATURES xColor On p.ProductID = xColor.ProductID
Inner Join LOOKUP lColor On xColor.LookupID = lColor.LookupID
Inner Join LOOKUP_CATEGORY lcColor On lColor.CategoryID = lcColor.LookupCategoryID And lcColor.Category = 'Color'
Left Join PRODUCT_FEATURES xFactor On p.ProductID = xFactor.ProductID
Inner Join LOOKUP lFactor On xFactor.LookupID = lFactor.LookupID
Inner Join LOOKUP_CATEGORY lcFactor On lFactor.CategoryID = lcFactor.LookupCategoryID And lcFactor.Category = 'Form Factor'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also write it as below, if you want it truely to be dynamic you'd have to generate the statement below using dynamic SQL techniques, see [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query):

```
Select ProductId,
ProductName,
Test.[Product type],
Test.[DIMM Type],
Test.[Speed],
Test.[Color],
Test.[Form Factor]

 From

(SELECT 
P.ProductID, 
p.ProductName, 
Category,
value

FROM imp.PRODUCT_FEATURES f 
LEFT JOIN imp.PRODUCT p ON p.productID = f.ProductID
LEFT JOIN imp.LOOKUP l ON l.lookupID = f.LookupID
LEFT JOIN imp.LOOKUP_CATEGORY lc ON lc.lookupcategoryID = l.CategoryID
) dt

pivot (max(dt.[value]) for dt.[CATEGORY] in ([Product type],[DIMM Type],[Speed],[Color],[Form Factor])) as test
```

For convenience..
--Create the schema IMP first..

```
/****** Object:  Table [imp].[Lookup]    Script Date: 8/1/2018 1:48:28 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [imp].[Lookup](
    [lookupID] [float] NULL,
    [CategoryID] [float] NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [imp].[Lookup_category]    Script Date: 8/1/2018 1:48:28 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [imp].[Lookup_category](
    [lookupcategoryID] [float] NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [imp].[Product]    Script Date: 8/1/2018 1:48:28 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [imp].[Product](
    [ProductID] [float] NULL,
    [ProductName] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [imp].[Product_features]    Script Date: 8/1/2018 1:48:28 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [imp].[Product_features](
    [ID] [float] NULL,
    [ProductID] [float] NULL,
    [LookupID] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (1, 1, N'DRAM')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (2, 1, N'Keyboard')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (3, 1, N'Headset')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (4, 2, N'Buffered')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (5, 2, N'Unbuffered')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (6, 3, N'Red')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (7, 3, N'White')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (8, 3, N'Yellow')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (9, 4, N'2000Mhz')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (10, 4, N'2300Mhz')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (11, 4, N'2600Mhz')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (12, 5, N'DIMM')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (13, 5, N'SODIMM')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (14, 5, N'Earbud')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup] ([lookupID], [CategoryID], [Value]) VALUES (15, 5, N'On-Ear')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup_category] ([lookupcategoryID], [Category]) VALUES (1, N'Product Type')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup_category] ([lookupcategoryID], [Category]) VALUES (2, N'DIMM Type')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup_category] ([lookupcategoryID], [Category]) VALUES (3, N'Color')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup_category] ([lookupcategoryID], [Category]) VALUES (4, N'Speed')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Lookup_category] ([lookupcategoryID], [Category]) VALUES (5, N'Form Factor')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product] ([ProductID], [ProductName]) VALUES (1, N'Memory1')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product] ([ProductID], [ProductName]) VALUES (2, N'Memory2')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product] ([ProductID], [ProductName]) VALUES (3, N'Headset1')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product] ([ProductID], [ProductName]) VALUES (4, N'Headset2')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product] ([ProductID], [ProductName]) VALUES (5, N'Keyboard1')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product] ([ProductID], [ProductName]) VALUES (6, N'Keyboard2')
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (1, 1, 1)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (2, 1, 4)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (3, 1, 10)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (4, 1, 12)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (5, 2, 1)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (6, 2, 5)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (7, 2, 9)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (8, 2, 13)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (9, 3, 3)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (10, 3, 7)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (11, 3, 15)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (12, 4, 3)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (13, 4, 6)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (14, 4, 14)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (15, 5, 2)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (16, 5, 7)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (17, 6, 2)
GO
INSERT [imp].[Product_features] ([ID], [ProductID], [LookupID]) VALUES (18, 6, 8)
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouping might be able to simplify it a bit.

```
SELECT
f.ProductID, 
p.ProductName, 
MAX(CASE WHEN lc.Category = 'Product Type' THEN l.Value END) AS ProductType, 
MAX(CASE WHEN lc.Category = 'DIMM Type' THEN l.Value END) AS DimmType, 
MAX(CASE WHEN lc.Category = 'Speed' THEN l.Value END) AS Speed, 
MAX(CASE WHEN lc.Category = 'Color' THEN l.Value END) AS Color, 
MAX(CASE WHEN lc.Category = 'Form Factor' THEN l.Value END) AS FormFactor
FROM PRODUCT_FEATURES f 
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT p ON p.ID = f.ProductID
LEFT JOIN LOOKUP l ON l.ID = f.LookupID
LEFT JOIN LOOKUP_CATEGORY lc ON lc.ID = l.CategoryID
GROUP BY f.ProductID, p.ProductName
```